# Laravel Show not authorised if user opens admin route

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Here are two routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:superAdmin']], function() {
Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\AdminController@getDashboard');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => ['role:user']], function() {
Route::get('/profile', 'User\UserController@getProfile');
});
```

If user try to access /admin/dashboard Not authorized view should be show.

Comment: what error/page your getting currently ?

Comment: HttpException in Application.php line 882 , i need custom error page for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept Exceptions in Laravel and do whatever you want to do with them. In this case you can catch the HTTP exception and then show a view or controller.

Check out the `render()` method here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#the-exception-handler